# Time Complexity of $addToset vs $push when element does not exist in the Array

Tags: mongodb

Given: Connection is Safe=True so Update's return will contain update information.

Say I have a documents that look like:

```
[{'a': [1]}, {'a': [2]}, {'a': [1,2]}]
```

And I issue:

```
coll.update({}, {'$addToSet': {'a':1}}, multi=True)
```

The result would be:

```
{u'connectionId': 28,
 u'err': None,
 u'n': 3,
 u'ok': 1.0,
 u'updatedExisting': True
}
```

Even when come documents already have that value. To avoid this I could issue a command.

```
coll.update({'a': {'$ne': 1}}, {'$push': {'a':1}}, multi=True)
```

What's the Time Complexity Comparison for $addToSet vs. $push with a $ne check ?

Comment: What do you mean by "time complexity" do you mean the amount of time taken by the comparison in relation to `$push`?

Comment: Yes.
If $push with a $ne is going to run through every element, which I assume $addToSet also does.
Which one of the two is optimal to be used ?

Comment: $push easily, since even though $push has to pull out the array (subdocument) it doesn't have to compare to set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like *$addToSet* is doing the same thing as your command: *$push with a $ne check*. Both would be O(N)

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/ops/update_internal.cpp

if speed is really important then why not use a hash:

instead of:

```
{'$addToSet': {'a':1}}
{'$addToSet': {'a':10}}
```

use:

```
{$set: {'a.1': 1}
{$set: {'a.10': 1}
```

Comment: Hmm I say addtoset was O(n) yet I get downvoted...must be wrong

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

Ok since I read your question wrong all along it turns out that actually you are looking at two different queries and judging the time complexity between them.

The first query being:

```
coll.update({}, {'$addToSet': {'a':1}}, multi=True)
```

And the second being:

```
coll.update({'a': {'$ne': 1}}, {'$push': {'a':1}}, multi=True)
```

First problem springs to mind here, no indexes. `$addToSet`, being an update modifier, I do not believe it uses an index as such you are doing a full table scan to accomplish what you need.

In reality you are looking for all documents that do not have `1` in `a` already and looking to `$push` the value `1` to that `a` array.

So 2 points to the second query even before we get into time complexity here because the first query:

- Does not use indexes
- Would be a full table scan
- Would then do a full array scan (with no index) to `$addToSet`

So I have pretty much made my mind up here that the second query is what your looking for before any of the Big O notation stuff.

There is a problem to using big O notation to explain the time complexity of each query here:

- I am unsure of what perspective you want, whether it is per document or for the whole collection.
- I am unsure of indexes as such. Using indexes will actually create a Log algorithm on `a` however not using indexes does not.

However the first query would look something like: O(n) per document since:

- The $addToSet would need to iterate over each element
- The $addToSet would then need to do an O(1) op to insert the set if it does not exist. I should note I am unsure whether the O(1) is cancelled out or not (light reading suggests my version), I have cancelled it out here.

Per collection, without the index it would be: O(2n2) since the complexity of iterating `a` will expodentially increase with every new document.

The second query, without indexes, would look something like: O(2n2) (O(n) per document) I believe since `$ne` would have the same problems as `$addToSet` without indexes. However with indexes I believe this would actually be O(log n log n) (O(log n) per document) since it would first find all documents with `a` in then all documents without `1` in their set based upon the b-tree.

So based upon time complexity and the notes at the beginning I would say query 2 is better.

If I am honest I am not used to explaining in "Big O" Notation so this is experimental.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Well your last line is my question.
Its ($addToSet) vs ($push + $ne).

Both of them would work, but if i had to rate them in terms of Big O, how would each score ?

Comment: @meson10 You keep using slang and I keep not understanding because I don't use the same slang as you, what is "Big O"? Also I do state that $push is faster for "time complexity".

Comment: In computer science, the time complexity of an algorithm quantifies the amount of time taken by an algorithm to run as a function of the size of the input to the problem. The time complexity of an algorithm is commonly expressed using big O notation, which suppresses multiplicative constants and lower order terms. When expressed this way, the time complexity is said to be described asymptotically, i.e., as the input size goes to infinity. For example, if the time required by an algorithm on all inputs of size n is at most 5n3 + 3n, the asymptotic time complexity is O(n3) http://smnr.me/TNAp7n

Comment: @meson10 Ok I am not used to beating around the bush with math syntax, instead I am used to explaining this with plain English however I, after 50 mins of reading into Big O notation, think I have been able to translate my English into math. I will edit if I see mistakes.

Comment: I think you have misread my question. 
I am not comparing $addToSet with a $ne vs $push. I mean to compare $addToSet vs ($push + $ne).
NOTE: Mind it there is no $ne lookup while i do an $addToSet.

Secondly, the "math" syntax is a more standard way of denoting metrics.
Example: Car A is so much faster than B Or Car A is 80kmph faster than B :-)

Comment: @meson10 Ah I was confused cos you showed the query: `coll.update({'a': {'$ne': 1}}, {'$addToSet': {'a':1}}, multi=True)` Which is why I gave that answer. So I thought it was $adToSet+$ne vs $ne+$push

Comment: @meson10 Also do you mean big o notation per document atomic update or per collection update, also using and not using indexes will change the big O notation for this since it would be a log algorithm on $ne but not on $addToSet which means $addToSet is still worse.

Comment: @meson10 I am not sure if that is a good example of the differences since "faster" is useless as such plain English would be "80kmph faster". I would compare this more to saying in plain English that the car is 80kmph faster and in big o type notation saying that O = T+80 where T equals the speed of the current car you are measuring against. Of course the sum is actually more complex than that but you see what I mean...

Answer (score 2):

Adding my observation in difference between addToSet and push from bulk update of 100k documents.

when you are doing bulk update. addToSet will be executed separately.

for example,

```
bulkInsert.find({x:y}).upsert().update({"$set":{..},"$push":{ "a":"b" } , "$setOnInsert":  {} })
```

will first insert and set the document. And then it executes addToSet query.

I saw clear difference of 10k between

```
db.collection_name.count() #gives around 40k 

db.collection_name.count({"a":{$in:["b"]}}) # it gives only around 30k
```

But when replaced $addToSet with $push. both count query returned same value.

note: when you're not concerned about duplicate entry in array. you can go with $push.