# MongoDB $addToSet vs $push (speed)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, time-complexity, mongodb-query

I have a collection of 150 million documents in a database in MongoDB and I want to add an array field to each document (keywords)

```
{ 
    Subject: "value1", 
    Object: "value2", 
    "keywords": [A,A,B,C,D]
}
```

So the field I want to add elements to is "keywords".
Should I do `addToSet(A)` or `push(A)`? I don't care about duplicates. So the above example is correct. But I only care about speed. which one is faster (time wise) `$addToSet` or `$push` ??

Comment: Is it really hard for you to try to insert 100k elements with addToSet and then 100k with push and check which one is better? Or you do not know how to make a benchmark?

Comment: [performance comparison between addToSet and push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225748/time-complexity-of-addtoset-vs-push-when-element-does-not-exist-in-the-array/34195794#34195794)

Answer (score 4):

The `push()` should be faster, because it has not to check for duplicates like `addToSet()` needs to. There is also a description on [how to profile](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/design-notes/#database-profiling) in the documentation if you want to test both methods in a real world like setup.